# parse JSON using json.net c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have to parse following JSON using *newtonsoft.net* using c#. I tried many codes but they are not working.

```
{
    "tableId": 1,
    "userId": 12,
    "branchId": 2,
    "cart": [{
        "itemId": 12,
        "itemname": "Paneer butter masala",
        "qty": "1",
        "price": "2500",
        "customise": [{
            "name": "fruit boul",
            "id": 1,
            "price": "25"
        }, {
            "name": "fruit boul",
            "id": 1,
            "price": "25"
        }],
        "comment": "",
        "linetotal": "2550"
    }, {
        "itemId": 34,
        "itemname": "Paneer butter masala",
        "qty": "1",
        "price": "2500",
        "customise": [{}],
        "comment": "",
        "linetotal": "2500"
    }],
    "total": "5050"
}
```

Any answer will highly appreciated.

Comment: *I tried many codes but they are not working.* What have you tried? And what is *not working* with those "codes"? Include your most promising attempt and tell us what isn't working. Will it not compile? Does it give you errors at run time? Does it run but does something other than you expected? What did you want to parse this into anyway?

Comment: I tried with JObject.Parse(), JToken, JArray, etc. I want each Items in cart, items in customise array

Comment: You need to **show** us your attempt, which means including your C# code in your post. As of right now, it's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. Make some models (or Plain Old C# Classes if you like) to deserialize your json into (generated by http://json2csharp.com/) - this is generally a little bit easier to work with that straight up json:

```
public class Customise
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
}

public class Cart
{
    public int itemId { get; set; }
    public string itemname { get; set; }
    public string qty { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public List<Customise> customise { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public string linetotal { get; set; }
}

public class TableData
{
    public int tableId { get; set; }
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public int branchId { get; set; }
    public List<Cart> cart { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
}
```

Step 2. Add Json.NET dependency to your project via NuGet package manager

Step 3. Deserialize your JSON string as such to get a object instance with all values set (I named your root object `TableData`, this can obviously be changed):

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TableData>(jsonString);
```

Now all the json data has been set inside the `data` object.

Comment: Thanks nbokmans. It's working as expected

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` here is a sample

```
var jsonFilePath = path to your file;

var myObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(jsonFile));
```

**How to automatically create proper classes having json data?**

If you don't want to manually create the proper class using your json data, you can select all your json text and the in the Visual Studio follow these steps:

> Edit > Paste Special > Paste as Json as Classes

[image]